# Toggle buttons between each other in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to make a container with 4 buttons in it and I wan't to toggle them between each other. Currently toggle is works when I double click the button (1click - show, 2click -hide) But when I click another button with toggle option the button shows information about another one.

How i can make button toggle when i click another button but not the same one.

```
<div class="newsFeedButtons">
  <button class="btn" id="searchbtn" onclick="searchFeed()">Search</button>
  <button class="btn" id="cryptobtn" onclick="cryptoFeed()">Crypto</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="twitterFeed()">Twitter</button>
</div>

<div id="twitterDIV" style="display: none;">
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="550" data- 
height="400" href="https://twitter.com/Bitcoin? 
ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by Bitcoin</a> 

<script async 
 src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8">. 
 </script>
 </div>

  <div class="row">
               <div id="newsResult"></div>
            </div>
```

JavaScript code:

```
function twitterFeed() {
  var x = document.getElementById("twitterDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
$(function() {
  $("form").submit(function() {
    return false;
  });
});

function searchFeed() {
  var x = document.getElementById("newsResult");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
$(function() {
  $("form").submit(function() {
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: First of all you're doing tons of mixing between vanillajs and jquery selectors, although that's fine I'd recommend you stick to one of them to stay consistant. What do you mean by toggling 4 buttons? What do you want to happen to other buttons when one of them is clicked?

Comment: Share your full html `div with id="twitterDIV" div with id="newsResult" missing `

Comment: @DaCurse So basically, when I trigger one button it shows the content which i want, but when i click another one, the content also appears but it goes above another. I wan't to hide content when i click another button, and the new content appears. I'm sorry if it's hard to explain. When i click 1button - contents appears. When i click second time on 1button content disappears. When I click on 1 button and then on 2 button i have both contents on a screen, i wan't to hide first content and show second content. Is it more correct?

Comment: @jobayersozib I edit the main question. Thank you for reminding me about this divs as well. Also refer to my another comment I hope I explain myself more correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A kind of simple toggling you can use on other elements, too:

```js
function showContent() {
    $('[data-show]').each(function(e) {
        var thisButton = $(this);
        var thisTarget = $( thisButton.data('show') );
        thisTarget.toggleClass('active', thisButton.hasClass('active'));
    });
};
showContent();
$('[data-show]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var thisButton = $(this);
    thisButton.siblings().removeClass('active');
    thisButton.addClass('active');
    showContent();
});
```

```css
.newsFeedButtons .active {
    border-color: red;
}
.newsFeedContent > div {
    display: none;
}
.newsFeedContent > div.active {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="newsFeedButtons">
    <button class="btn active" data-show="#searchDiv">Search</button>
    <button class="btn" data-show="#cryptoDIV">Crypto</button>
    <button class="btn" data-show="#twitterDIV">Twitter</button>
</div>
<div class="newsFeedContent">
    <div id="searchDiv">Search...</div>
    <div id="cryptoDIV">Crypto...</div>
    <div id="twitterDIV">Twitter...</div>
</div>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skobaljic/zw25qat7/16/)

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation**
Everytime when you click a button it display a particular div to block.
But when you click other button previous div style remains `display:block`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="newsFeedButtons">
        <button class="btn" id="searchbtn" onclick="searchFeed()">Search</button>
        <button class="btn" id="cryptobtn" onclick="cryptoFeed()">Crypto</button>
        <button class="btn" id="twitterbtn" onclick="twitterFeed()">Twitter</button>
      </div>
      
      <div id="twitterDIV" style="display: none;">
            <a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="550" data- 
            height="400" href="https://twitter.com/Bitcoin? 
            ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by Bitcoin</a> 
      </div>
      
        <div class="row">
            <div id="newsResult" style="display:none">News result div</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div id="cryptoDIV" style="display:none">Crypto div</div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
        
        function twitterFeed() {
    var x = document.getElementById("twitterDIV");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      x.style.display = "none";
    }
    document.getElementById("newsResult").style="display:none";
    document.getElementById("cryptoDIV").style="display:none";
  }
  $(function() {
    $("form").submit(function() {
      return false;
    });
  });
  
  function searchFeed() {
     
    var x = document.getElementById("newsResult");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      x.style.display = "none";
    }

    document.getElementById("twitterDIV").style="display:none";
    document.getElementById("cryptoDIV").style="display:none";
  }

  function cryptoFeed() {
     
    var x = document.getElementById("cryptoDIV");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      x.style.display = "none";
    }

    document.getElementById("twitterDIV").style="display:none";
    document.getElementById("newsResult").style="display:none";
  }


  $(function() {
    $("form").submit(function() {
      return false;
    });
  });
        </script>
        <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

</body>
</html>
```